# Obtener Url de un hyperlink y función en JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe

estoy haciendo un iframe que muestre diferentes aplicaciones de acuerdo al rol de usuario que se tenga, y para esto en la pagina Inicio.aspx te muestra dichas aplicaciones, de acuerdo a este código:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ui_rprApp" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsApp">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <li>
        <div class='<%# "ch-item " + Eval("ESTILO_APP") %>'>

            <div class="ch-info">
            <p>
             <asp:HyperLink ID="ui_hlkApp" runat="server" Target='<%# Eval("ACRONIMO") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("URL") %>'>
                 <%# Eval("DESCRIPCION") %>
             </asp:HyperLink>
            </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>                               
  </ItemTemplate>
```

Quiero obtener el URL que Hyperlink contiene para así poderlo usarlo en una función con javascript que está abra Aplicaciones_Usuarios.aspx que es el iframe, y este ponerlo en el Pageload de mi iframe así mostrar la aplicación seleccionada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Quiero obtener el URL que Hyperlink contiene para así poderlo usarlo en una función con javascript

Podrias en vez de tenerlo que recuperar, realizar la accion en un metodo javascript que dispares desde el hyperlink

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="ui_hlkApp" runat="server" 
            Target='<%# Eval("ACRONIMO") %>' 
            NavigateUrl='javascript:metodoAbrir('<%# Eval("URL") %>');return false;'>
<%# Eval("DESCRIPCION") %>
```

En este ejemplo mira como dispara el evento metodoAbrir (es un ejemplo, alli deberias llamar al metodo javascript que necesites en tu app, ejemplo app.irA, etc) Avisanos si necesitas ayuda en el metodo javascript

```
javascript:metodoAbrir('<%# Eval("URL") %>');return false;
```

El ultimo return false; es para que el enlace no tenga el efecto de ir hace arriba de la pagina. Es decir se cancela la accion;

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guia

Answer (score 0):

Cuando el servidor renderiza el elemento `<asp:Hyperlink />`, se muestra como un elemento `<a href="controlador.aspx" />`. A partir de ahí, podés tomar el atributo `href` del elemento `<a/>` de la siguiente forma:

```js
let hyperlink = document.getElementById('hyperlink_id').href;
```